# Linux script , Incremental backup in the same server

Tags: linux, scripting, shell, bin

Could you please someone guide for the below incremental backup script, i have already written the script. I am facing an issue while looping the script.

Requirement i need : Consider a source folder contains A, B, C when i ran the script A, B, C will move to the destination folder.
Again in source folder new files/directories added i.e. D,E when again if i ran the script now it should check for already present files. Here in our case A,B,C is already present in the destination. So only D,E have to move to the destination.

From the below code am able to backup , but how to make in loop Please guide

```
#!/bin/bash
####################################
#
# Backup IS server script script.
#
####################################

# What to backup. 
Integrationserver="/home/ec2-user/source"

# Where to backup to.
dest="/home/ec2-user/destination"


# Create archive filename.
#date=$(date +%F)
IS=source
hostname=$(hostname -s)
#archive_file="$hostname-$IS-$date.tar.gz"
archive_file="$hostname-$IS.tar.gz"

# Print start status message.
echo "Backing up $Integrationserver to $dest/$archive_file"
date
echo

# Backup the files using tar.
tar --exclude=/home/ec2-user/source/logs* --exclude=/home/ec2-user/source/TC*  -zcf $dest/$archive_file $Integrationserver

# Print end status message.
echo
echo "Backup finished"
date
```

The below code is working fine with all the conditions and requirements , But not sure how to exclude the multiple directories.. please guide

```
#!/bin/bash

source=/home/ec2-user/source
dest=/home/ec2-user/destination

for file in $(find $source -printf "%P\n") ; do
  if [ -a $dest/$file ] ; then
    if [ $source/$file -nt $dest/$file ]; then
      echo "Newer file detected, copying .."
      cp -r $source/$file $dest/$file
    else
      echo "File $file exists, skipping"
    fi 
  else
    echo "$file is being copied over to $dest"
    cp -r $source/$file $dest/$file
  fi 
done
```

Comment: You want the script to keep executing in an infinite loop, is it?

Comment: @Vinicius, yes i want to like that , but in that i need to exclude few directories. Could you please help

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem? If so, please accept it.

Comment: @Vinicius, Thank you for sharing the script. I have used the first script , its working fine. After running the script , the script is not ending from the result terminal . Manually i am stopping the script .. please assist , Automatically how can the script stop after copying.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you need, you first asked for a infinite loop. If you don't want it to loop for ever just run the `rsync`, you don't need the `while true`. What am I missing?

Comment: @Vinicius , I mean to say the script is going to infinite loop. Once if the files copied from source to destination, then the loop should breakout.

Comment: Ok, look at the updated answer

Comment: @Vinicius, thank you so much !!! for the updated answer

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to accept the answer so it can help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a much simpler script using `rsync`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source=/home/ec2-user/source
dest=/home/ec2-user/destination

changed=0

while [[ $changed -eq 0 ]]; do
    # The next command just count changes, does not copy anything
    changed=$(rsync -rin $source/ $dest | grep "^>f" | wc -l)
    sleep 1
done

echo "Copying $changed files"

rsync -qrt $source/ $dest
```

I used the `sleep 1` to avoid a resource intensive loop, but there is a better way using inotify-tools:

```
inotifywait -e modify,create -r $source && \
  rsync -qrt $source/ $dest
```

The `inotifywait` command will stay blocked until some file is either modified or created (the `-e modify,create` option) and it is very efficient.